# Images aren't loading online on my GitHub web page

Tags: html, css, github

GitHub won't load the images in my images folder. It loads the background image fine, and all the images load when I launch the page offline. I've made sure the images only begin with letters, and tried matching the image file names with the path names in the `index.html` file case sensitive-wise but still no luck.

website: http://rpboyer15.github.io/sounds-of-the-storm/

repo: https://github.com/rpboyer15/sounds-of-the-storm

Comment: At a glance it looks like you've got the cases mixed up. `Abathur.jpg` != `abathur.jpg` If I change that one it works.

Answer (score 2):

Paths are case sensitive. For example in your repository, you have `brightwing.jpg` and in your HTML you have `Brightwing.jpg` which will result in a 404. If you use the Chrome Dev Tools and adjust the URL using Inspect Element and it will load properly.

[image]

PS: Heroes is an awesome game.

Comment: You're right, that does the trick. Except now I've realized that my page hasn't been updating with my changes. I've made all the filenames in the index.html file lowercase, but the page source is still viewing them as capitalized.

Comment: nevermind, it seems I didn't follow the directions on setting up gh-pages at https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually/ closely enough